# How to set up a LAN between Multiple Residences

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

How can I set up an environment such as a LAN accessible over the Internet?

I previously had a LAN at my house behind my ISP's router. I had my 192.168.1.1 router with all my clients on it consisting of computers, tablets, Roku, etc. I was able to ssh to computers, share files via NFS and automounts, boot over PXE as needed, etc.

The router itself ran Tomato, but I also had a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian that I used as a CUPS print server.

I now have the residence split into two separate apartments, each with its own Internet connection from different ISPs in different neighborhoods--too far for Wi-Fi or an Ethernet cable between them.

I would like to maintain some of the conveniences as before such as file sharing between some of not all clients via NFS mounts and PXE booting as if they were on the same LAN.

I still have the Tomato router at one residence and a DD-WRT router at the other. I still have the Raspbian device at one residence and can set up others as needed. Each of my routers sits behind its corresponding ISP-provided router that I don't touch much beyond allowing port 22 to come through to one client behind the routers.

I am currently considering setting up something with OpenVPN unless a better recommendation comes along.

Comment: VPN is indeed what you need.

Comment: Connecting LAN segements with OpenVPN is a bit tricky, you need special configuration (google). Consider using e.g [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org) instead, that's easier to set up.

Comment: Also, it's not aLAN when you have those distances (it could be a WAN or a MAN or a network, but it's not a **local** area network.